# Change ErrorText "Incorrect user ID or password."

Tags: javascript, office365, adfs

When logging into Office 365 through AD FS sign-in page, I get this error text when inputting an incorrect password: *Incorrect user ID or password. Type the correct user ID and password, and try again.*
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROluB.jpg)

I would like to change it. I've been able to change **userNameFormatError** and **passwordEmpty** messages by editing the onload.js as explained here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636121.aspx but not the incorrect password text. I've used FireFox and Chrome's dev tools to monitor how it changes to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var labelAuthfailed = document.getElementById("errorText") ;
if ( labelAuthfailed && labelAuthfailed.innerHTML == "Incorrect user ID or password. Type the correct user ID and password, and try again.") {
    labelAuthfailed.innerHTML = "Booh! Fat fingers!" ;
}
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/dd86453b-eaf4-49d3-9c8c-ba74db2ddff5